# pygraphviz: find the lowest ranking node in the subgraph / graph

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to find the lowest ranking node because I want to always put something at the very bottom of the graph. Is there a way to do something like `G.lowest_rank()` and it would return the string of the node?

If not, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using right now, so we have a full working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are special values for subraph [rank](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rank) attribute called `max` and `sink` which allow you to put a node in the lowest rank.

- If you use `rank=max` then the node will appear on the already existing lowest rank.
- If you use `rank=sink` then the node have its own rank which is below the lowest rank of the graph, example:

```
digraph {
    a -> b -> c
    {
        rank=max
        bottom1 [label="rank=max"]
    }
}
```

[image: max]

```
digraph {
    a -> b -> c
    {
        rank=sink
        bottom1 [label="rank=sink"]
    }
}
```

[image: sink]

I am not too familiar with PyGraphviz, but to achieve the same result there you can do something like this:

```py
G = pgv.AGraph(directed=True)
G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.add_node('c')
G.add_node('bottom1', label="rank=sink")
G.add_edge('a','b')
G.add_edge('b','c')
G.add_subgraph(['bottom1'], name='s1', rank='sink')
```